# VB6 ms access sql query distinct count two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, dao

I need to output per a specific employee this data:
employee_Id, employee_name, presence.year, presence.month, count(day), sum(work hours), sum(holiday hours), [work hours] - [holiday hours].
I used this query on vb6 project but it seems not working good:

```
SELECT
     Employees.Employee_ID AS ID
     , Employees.Full_Name AS Name
     , Presence.Yr AS Year
     , Presence.Mnth AS Month
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Dy, 1, 0)) Work_Days
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Hr, Presence.Hr, 0)) AS Work_Hours
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Holidays, Presence.Holidays, 0)) AS Holidays_Hours
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Hr, Presence.Hr, 0)) - SUM(IIF(Presence.Holidays, Presence.Holidays, 0) AS Total_Work_Hours
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Presence ON Presence.Employee_ID = Employees.Employee_ID
WHERE Employees.Company = 'aCompany'
     AND Employees.Employee_ID = 'anEmmployee'
GROUP BY  Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Full_Name, Presence.Yr, Presence.Mnth
```

Like this in the picture: http://oi60.tinypic.com/122c6xz.jpg

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you provide us the expected result? First of all, remove `Presence.Dy, Presence.Hr, Presence.Holidays` from your GROUP BY clause, you can also remove the `DISTINCT` from your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Need to have this table as result: http://oi60.tinypic.com/122c6xz.jpg

Comment: Ok and what is the current result that gives your query? Did you try with the corrections I mentioned?

Comment: In the ID column it shows the one I inserted, but on the name column show all the other employee names in the table

Comment: The title of this question is horrible. It looks like all you did was throw keywords and tags at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query with some adjustments:

```
SELECT
     Employees.Employee_ID AS ID
     , Employees.Full_Name AS Name
     , Presence.Yr AS Year
     , Presence.Mnth AS Month
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Dy, 1, 0)) Work_Days
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Hr, Presence.Hr, 0)) AS Work_Hours
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Holidays, Presence.Holidays, 0)) AS Holidays_Hours
     , SUM(IIF(Presence.Hr, Presence.Hr, 0)) - SUM(IIF(Presence.Holidays, Presence.Holidays, 0) AS Total_Work_Hours
     , SUM(Presence.Hr) / Employees.HoursPerDay + Employees.TotalAnnualHolidays - Employees.DoneHolidays AS AvailableHolidays
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Presence ON Presence.Employee_ID = Employees.Employee_ID
WHERE Employees.Company = 'aCompany'
     AND Employees.Employee_ID = 'anEmmployee'
GROUP BY  Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Full_Name, Employees.HoursPerDay, Employees.TotalAnnualHolidays, Employees.DoneHolidays, Presence.Yr, Presence.Mnth
```

Can you test this new query and give me info about the result and the difference with what you're looking for?

Hope this will help.

Comment: The query seem to work good, but when it comes to null values it shows an error. How to avoid null values or set them to 0?

Comment: I updated the query in order to replace NULL values, can you test it and tell me if it works better?

Comment: I shows an syntax error at the first CASE. Is this syntax also functional for ms access??

Comment: I fixed it using IIF statement instead of CASE, but when I run the software, it shows an error: Object doesn't support this property or method. The results are shown in the DBGrid but there is this error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new query you used and the detail of the error?

Comment: I updated the query. Now it is working properly. I wanted to add a new column like this: `SUM(Presence.Hr)\Employees.HoursPerDay + Employees.TotalAnnualHolidays - Employees.DoneHolidays AS AvailableHolidays`

Comment: I accepted your edition, i wasn't aware about the specificity of msaccess.

Comment: When I updated the query with this row: 
`SUM(Presence.Hr) / Employees.HoursPerDay + Employees.TotalAnnualHolidays - Employees.DoneHolidays AS AvailableHolidays` it show an error that says: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "my added row",  as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: I updated my answer with the new column you was trying to add. The releved error is simple, when you use `GROUP BY`clause it's important to enumerate every columns that are used in the `SELECT`outside the aggregate functions (in this case i simply added the 3 new columns you used).